# difference between uniformly convex norms and strictly subadditive norms?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

> What is the difference between **uniformly convex** norms and **strictly subadditive** norms?
>   why we need to define two above concept? how they help us to study Banach spaces?
>   Is the norm induced by inner product simultaneously uniformly convex and strictly subadditive norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a uniformly convex norm the condition of strict subadditivity has to hold uniformly in the following sense;

For any pair of unit vectors $x,y$, the norm of $(x+y)/2$ is strictly less than 1 by an amount that depends only on $|x-y|$. More explicitly, there is an increasing function $\epsilon(r)$ defined for positive $r$,
$$\epsilon(r)>0, \quad \lim_{r\to0} \epsilon(r)=0,$$
such that for all $x,y$ in the unit ball $|x|\leq 1, |y|\leq1$, the inequality
$$\left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right|\leq 1- \epsilon(|x-y|),$$
holds.

Based on this it should be clear what properties a norm induced by a inner product has.